# Completely Remove Siri

Tags: macos, siri

Periodically I see this popup on my MacOS 10.12.6 screen:

[image]

One case of it popping up is when I accidentally press a button on my headset.

Here is the setting in my system preferences:

[image]

How can I completely remove it?

There is no case when I will want to enable it so I don't mind a solution that is irreversible.

I tried to move it to Trash and got this:

[image]

I followed @bmike suggestion of turning on Siri and immediately turning it off.  I received this warning about sending my contacts to Apple:

[image]

Despite not wanting to send my contacts to Apple I did enable and then disable.

I still get the "Do you want to enable Siri?"

Comment: Once you turn on Siri and then turn it off, the nag doesn't fire for that major version. Are you looking for a guide on disabling system integrity protection and then having upgrades replace parts and all of Siri or just a more pragmatic - turn it off? Basically, I believe you've disabled it now permanently as long as you stay on 10.12

Comment: Yeah I would advise against removing any preinstalled features or applications and just disable them instead. Will save from potential problems in the future

Comment: "just disable them instead".  Sure, how do I do that?

Comment: Mojave fixes this issue though. Turning it off after enabling doesn't poke again. Not suggesting you to update it, just letting you know where this solution comes from..